# Is it advisable to use the Extra Virgin Olive oil for Indian cooking, and baking?

Tags: indian-cuisine, olive-oil

I use this oil for baking cup cakes, and I add this oil to the whole wheat dough meant for preparing parathas on the gas stove?

My mother uses it for frying vegetables on the gas stove.

Hence the question in the title. Should I be vary of anything here?

Comment: The duplicate is somewhat more general than this one, but specifically deals with olive oil too. We also have tons of other questions on frying with olive oil, for example http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17605/. If I misunderstood why you are asking this (I don't see how the cupcakes are relevant to frying?) and these are not duplicates, please edit.

Comment: That is a waste of very expensive olive oil. When heated. Olive oil loses a lot of its beautiful flavour. Plus the spices in Indian cooking kill the olive oil flavour. That is why parathas are cooked in butter and ghee, these oils release flavour when heated.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use olive oil in indian cooking and baking. The olive flavor is not compatible with the flavors of most styles of indian food. I wouldn't use it for baking cup cakes in any style of cooking, I would recommend a more neutral flavored vegetable oil.