# Difference between butter and olive oil?

Tags: butter, olive-oil

Generally when I cook I use extra virgin olive oil for both meat and vegetables. While watching a cooking show they mentioned using butter instead of oil to grease the pan when they were cooking steak.

What is the end result different between using butter rather than olive oil and does it after vegetables and meat?

Comment: A bit off-topic: Do you use the extra virgin olive oil as cooking oil or for finishing? I recommend to use extra virgin olive oil only for finishing because it has a quite low smoke point. Refined oils are more suitable for frying.

Comment: I usually use extra virgin most of the food I make is sautéed. While I do usually carry both virgin and extra virgin olive oil in my pantry my go to is extra virgin until I run out.

Comment: Tip: [Can extra virgin olive oil be used for stir frying, roasting, grilling?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/17605/23376)

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to use butter instead of olive oil would be for the butter flavor. In restaurant cooking the steak is finished off with butter for flavor. If you do cook with butter you need to remember butter has a much lower burn point than olive oil.

Comment: *Extra virgin* olive oil has its smoke point at 130-180°C, butter ~175°C.